# python importing module ImportError

Tags: python, import, python-module

I am writing custom test runner for django app. In django app folder i got folder like this one[image: folder structure of my package]

But when i try to run tests I got error:

```
ERROR: AdminLoginTest (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: AdminLoginTest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\\python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 252, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "D:\\python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 230, in _get_module_f
rom_name
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\\selenium_tests\tests\admin_panel\AdminLoginTest.py",
line 1, in <module>
    from selenium_tests.SeleniumTestCase import SeleniumTestCase
ImportError: No module named selenium_tests.SeleniumTestCase
```

In SeleniumTestCase i got sth like this:

```
class SeleniumTestCase(TestCase):
   body
```

I believe it is something wrong with package not with my runner.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: your `selenium_tests` is not on your PYTHONPATH. Try adding an `__init__.py` to the `selenium_tests` directory.

Comment: I have __init__.pyfile in selenium_tests

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because, if I am right you run as a script (by running the unittests) the file `AdminLoginTest.py`. Running this script, the python interpreter cannot reach the directory of `selenium_tests`.

One solution would be to use relative imports, i.e.

`from ..selenium_tests.SeleniumTestCase import SeleniumTestCase`

However this will not either work because you are running the file `AdminLoginTest.py` as a script. Only if the file `AdminLoginTest.py` would be imported as a module you would be able to use relative imports.

I would propose to change the structure of your directory, having the unittests as a top level directory and all the other classes as lower level directories. The import would then work.

Comment: If I understand You correctly I should move selenium_tests/tests/* to selenium_tests/*?